# How to get RouteData by URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to get `RoutData` by given URL string in ASP.NET MVC application.

I've found the way that I need to mock `HttpContextBase` based on my URL string and then pass it to `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData()` method in [Route Parsing (Uri to Route)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1281667.aspx) thread.

*How to mock `HttpContextBase` to retrieve `RouteData` by URL string using `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData()`?* 
*Or is there another way to retrieve `RouteData` by URL?*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830052/how-do-i-get-the-controller-and-action-names-from-the-referrer-uri

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I used [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to determine what members of `HttpContextBase` are used in `GetRouteData()`. They are:

- Request

  - AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
  - PathInfo

`Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` should return path with `~`, what I exactly need, so utility class may be like this one:

```cs
public static class RouteUtils
{
    public static RouteData GetRouteDataByUrl(string url)
    {
        return RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new RewritedHttpContextBase(url));
    }

    private class RewritedHttpContextBase : HttpContextBase
    {
        private readonly HttpRequestBase mockHttpRequestBase;

        public RewritedHttpContextBase(string appRelativeUrl)
        {
            this.mockHttpRequestBase = new MockHttpRequestBase(appRelativeUrl);
        }


        public override HttpRequestBase Request
        {
            get
            {
                return mockHttpRequestBase;
            }
        }

        private class MockHttpRequestBase : HttpRequestBase
        {
            private readonly string appRelativeUrl;

            public MockHttpRequestBase(string appRelativeUrl)
            {
                this.appRelativeUrl = appRelativeUrl;
            }

            public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
            {
                get { return appRelativeUrl; }
            }

            public override string PathInfo
            {
                get { return ""; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this (for example on *`~/Error/NotFound`*):

```cs
var rd = RouteUtils.GetRouteDataByUrl("~/Error/NotFound")
```

Which should return an object that looks like this:

```cs
RouteData.Values
{
    controller = "Error",
    action = "NotFound"
}
```

Comment: It always comes null for me

Comment: This is problematic with QueryString

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (.NET 4.5, MVC 5):
https://average-joe.info/url-to-route-data/

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteData routeFromUrl =
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(
            new HttpContextWrapper(
                new HttpContext(
                    new HttpRequest(null, path, query),
                    new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StringWriter()))));
```

Comment: That StringWriter needs to be disposed.