# Routing issues in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get RouteData by URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545432/how-to-get-routedata-by-url)

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
            var index = url.IndexOf(".");

            if (index < 0)
                return null;

            var subDomain = url.Substring(0, index);

            if (subDomain != "www" && subDomain != "m")
            {
                var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Business"); 
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Display"); 
                    routeData.Values.Add("id", subDomain);
                return routeData;
            }

            if (subDomain == "m")
            {
                var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Mobile"); 
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); 

                return routeData;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

My problem is that when I access `xyz.mydomain.com` it is always rerouted to `xyz.mydomain.com/Business/Display/xyz`.  This is preventing me from going to `xyz.mydomain.com/Overview` as it's picking up the subdomain and redirecting.

I have tried using `if` statements to determine if a controller is specified, but nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just curious, what class are you overriding `GetRouteData` on?

Comment: Here is a post that answers your question: [How to get RouteData by URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545432/how-to-get-routedata-by-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else needs an answer this was my solution... 
The `substrings.Length >= 3` is for a controller then an action so change to 2 if you only need a controller :

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                var host = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
                var url = httpContext.Request.RawUrl;
                Regex regex = new Regex("/");
                string[] substrings = regex.Split(url);
                if (substrings.Length >= 3)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                var index = host.IndexOf(".");
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var subDomain = host.Substring(0, index);

                if (subDomain != "www" && subDomain != "m")
                {
                    var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Business"); //Goes to the User1Controller class
                        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Display"); //Goes to the Index action on the User1Controller
                        routeData.Values.Add("id", subDomain);
                    return routeData;
                }

                if (subDomain == "m")
                {
                    var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Mobile"); //Goes to the User2Controller class
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index"); //Goes to the Index action on the User2Controller

                    return routeData;
                }
                return null;
            }
```